# Delphi, String Grid is not selectable, How to make it selectable to select Row or Col?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, tstringgrid

I am having a StringGrid in Delphi 5 of fixed rows and Fixed Cols. But at run mode I am not able to select any row or any cell.

How and what is the property that allow me to make String Row or cell selectable.

Comment: Are all rows and columns fixed? Why? Normally you don't want fixed rows and columns to be selectable.

Comment: The term I used fixed in not in really fixed. At time of designing I gave as fixed but run time it will get populated. So don't go with that word but just the problem is with not selectable...

Comment: Can you clarify that? What's the value of `FixedCols` and `FixedRows`? Please also show the code to populate the string grid. You might try to rework the question to make your problem clearer.

Comment: Got the answer, problem with form.dfm setting

Answer (score 5):

You cannot select fixed rows and columns and that is intended behaviour as this is normally not wanted. Is there any reason you have these rows and columns fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the TStringGrid.Options property at design time. These have not changed much over the years and they are nearly all set to False. particularly: goEditing, goRowSelect.